# Is there an equivalent for respondsToSelector to check if a variable exists?

Tags: swift

Since iOS 8 there exists UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString.

My app will be for iOS7 and 8. How do I check if the constant is available or not (I know that I can check on OS version, but is there a more direct way?)

Comment: The following applies to Objective-C (not sure about Swift): If I remember correctly, if you build using base SDK of iOS 8 but deploy for iOS >= 7, you can check if the string is `nil` or not (i.e., at runtime, `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` will equal `nil` in iOS 7). Same applies for function names (e.g., `NSLog`).

Comment: Here is a blog post that touches this subject. http://www.russbishop.net/swift-respondstoselector

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the variable exists by looking at the address of the variable:

```
if (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != nil) {
    // UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString exists
} else {
    // don't use UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString
}
```

Comment: @Senior Why wouldn't it compile?

Comment: I get  'NSString' is not convertible to '@lvalue inout $T2' when attempting the check